# Negotiate for better pay amidst organization reshuffle

Tags: salary, united-states, negotiation

I've been working for the current IT company for almost 6 years now. I've stuck with this employer this long for personal reasons.
I've had 5 different managers here. Just right during performance review
I was shuffled into another team and the new manager gave me a
paltry 2% raise.

I've talked to her about the low raise (not even keeping up with inflation)
and not being paid market value. She said she does not have a say in budget
and she would have talk to her manager about this. It's been months and
there aren't news on this.

Now I've had a working relationship with my manager's manager before. Should I press her manager on this?

Comment: Try reminding her again she might have forgotten about it. If this happens again then you should go to her manager. There might be the case that she doesn't want to do anything about your situation but you know her manager well so you don't have to worry about it. If you go without giving her a second chance her ego might get hurts and you know what happens after any manager's ego gets hurt.

Comment: I would avoid going behind my managers back, unless I was sure they had absolutely no intention of following up.

Comment: @xml_dope All mgrs have fragile egos don't they?

Comment: @Concerned_Citizen` not all but most of them have a fragile ego and why not, They worked really hard to earn that position at least most of them.

Comment: Six years is too long. You're definitely not getting paid market value for your skills. You need to find a new employer.

Comment: In the past I've come across managers who're too scared or nervous to ask for stuff from their superiors. It's a shitty situation for you and I'm not sure there's an answer other than moving or at least transferring within the company.

Answer (score 5):

Don't go behind your managers back to their manager. That will probably not go well for you. If you think you earned this raise, make the case again with your manager and if it is the same answer, discuss together about going to your manager's manager. Then you can discuss out if you'll go by yourself. Don't cut corners here if you want to keep a healthy working relationship with your current manager.

Also - What if your bosses boss doesn't give you a raise either? Go behind their back as well, all the way until you're at the CEO? Probably not right? So do prepare what you need and decide what you will do if you don't get it.

Comment: Work is hard enough without all these unspoken and unwritten rules.  Why does the workplace have to be like a landmine?  SIGH........

Comment: @Concerned_Citizen ask Scott Adams. He basically wrote the rules.

Comment: The above comment is a joke, if anyone didn't get it.

Comment: "Don't go behind your managers back to their manager" without a plan B, anyway.